# Visibility problem for static files -- django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I connected static files in django, but they won't connect, can you help?

settings:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    "web_page/static",
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="{% static "css/standart_template.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <title>HouseVOP</title>
</head>
```

urls - projects:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls    import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/',      admin.site.urls),
    path('',            include('web_page.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

urls - app:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views      import FormListView, Success
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('',            FormListView,     name = 'home'),
    path('success/',    Success,          name = 'success')
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Before turning here, I searched many sites, so now I may simply not see something. In the first version of the code, I laid the path to the static files along with os.path.join (BASE_DIR, etc., but it did not work ...

Comment: try to replace STATICFILES_DIRS with `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]` to your settings.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

dont use web_page/static.no need to.